# Can I change category_id of images to null on deletion of said category?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables - `images` and `categories`. The `images` table has a column called `category_id` which takes the id of the category to which this image is assigned. I tried making `category_id` a foreign key that would be deleted on cascade but it didn't work out and maybe I'm not doing it correctly.

```
    Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('users')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('category_id')->nullable()->default(null)->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('categories')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('image_file_name');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });
```

The error I received was:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL
  : alter table `images` add constraint `images_category_id_foreign` foreign
  key (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`) on delete cascade)

After solving the migration problem it turned out that ->onDelete('cascade') is not what I was looking for. I just want to set the category_id to NULL on the image deletion, not delete the images as well.

Comment: did it throw any exception or it's just not working?

Comment: Oh, I received SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL
  : alter table `images` add constraint `images_category_id_foreign` foreign
  key (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: did you create the *categories* table first?

Comment: Well I use php artisan migrate so I'm not sure the order in which the tables are being created. Can I set it up in a way so that categories gets created first?

Comment: usually the migration file name starts with a date, so it must be sorted in the order which is going to run in, so just check order of the files

Comment: Well now it works, however, the effect I'm getting is not what I want. On category deletion, all images that have that category get deleted as well. I'm trying to just set their category_id columns to NULL.

Comment: if you are deleting category, then it must be like that due to onCascade('delete'). do you want to set *category_id* to null when deleting category?

Comment: Yes, this is my goal.

Comment: please add it to your question, im gonna answer it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the migration files affects the foreign keys, so to deal with this kind of problem there are two ways:

- create the tables in specific order so the foreign keys must be created after the related table.
- **OR** create new migration for the foreign keys, but make sure that this migration file is created after both tables.

---

For the second problem:
Calling `onDelete('cascade');` will delete any image related to the category your deleting.

Now if you want to set the foreign key *category_id* to null, just replace it with `->onDelete('set null')`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This migration doesn't have any error I think you should check whether categories table exists and the id column in categories table is unsigned integer(increment()).
I tested this migration on my system and it is running perfectly fine.

```
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });

    Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('category_id')->nullable()->default(null)->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('categories')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('image_file_name');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });
```